Proof that the hopfield network decreases the energy for simultaneous updates?
A hopfield network is given by an $N\times N$ matrix $w$ satisfying $w_{ij}=w_{ji}$ and operates on $N$-dimensional bitstrings, which we represent as $\{-1,1\}$. If a hopfield network updates each neuron one at a time, then it is easy to show that every update $x^{t+1}=sgn(wx^t)$ must decrease the energy $E(x)=-\sum_{ij}w_{ij}x_ix_j$, as follows:
We need to show that $E(x^{t+1})-E(x^t)\leq 0$, i.e. that $-\sum_{ij}w_{ij}x^{t+1}_ix^{t+1}_j + \sum_{ij}w_{ij}x^t_ix^t_j \leq 0$. Assume we only update $x_i$. Then for all $j\neq i$, $x^{t+1}_j=x^t_j$, so for the case $x^{t+1}=x^t$ we have $E(x^{t+1})-E(x^t) =0$, so assume the case $x^{t+1}=-x^t$. Then using the fact that $w_{ij}=w_{ji}$ we can rewrite it as $E(x^{t+1})-E(x^t) = (-x^{t+1}_i+x^t_i)(\sum_jw_{ij}x_j^t)$. But since $x_i^{t+1}=-x^t_i$ this equals $-2x^{t+1}_i(\sum_jw_{ij}x_j^t)$. But since by definition of the hopfield update rule we have $x^{t+1}_i=sgn(\sum_jw_{ij}x_j^t)$ we know this is equal to $-2(x^{t+1}_i)^2|\sum_jw_{ij}x_j^t|=-2|\sum_jw_{ij}x_j^t|\leq 0$.
However, I don't know how to generalize this to the case where all the variables are updated simultaneously. You might think that you can simply apply the above proof $N$ times, but this doesn't work: The next variables will not be update taking into account the previously updated variables. the update of $x^{t+1}_2$ will still assume the value $x^t_1$ as opposed to $x^{t+1}_1$, so we cannot apply the above trick.
So how do you prove it?
